# Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory Field Theory (pgs. 10 and 11)

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm working through Neukirch's *Algebriac Number Theory* for a reading course, but I'm getting hung up on some of the field theory stuff on pages 10 and 11.

On page 10, during the proof that $Tr_{L/K} \circ Tr_{M/L} = Tr_{M/K}$ for a tower of field extensions $K \subseteq L \subseteq M$, Neukirch partitions Hom$_K(L,\overline{K})$ by $\sigma \sim \tau$ if $\sigma|_L = \tau|_L$ into $m$ classes, each with representative $\sigma_i$. Now the part that's throwing me off is when he uses the fact that $$\sum_{\sigma \sim \sigma_i} \sigma x = Tr_{\sigma_i M/ \sigma_i L}(\sigma_i x).$$ I've got no idea where this could come from. It seems reasonable, but I've not been able to prove it using the definitions and propositions given.

On a different note, towards the top of page 11, Neukirch says that for the special case of a basis of the form $\{1, \theta, \dots, \theta^{n-1}\}$, we can determine that $d(1,\theta,\dots,\theta^{n-1}) = \prod_{i<j}(\theta_i - \theta_j)^2$ by "successively multiplying each of the first $n-1$ columns of the Vandermonde matrix by $\theta_1$ and subtracting it from the following", where $\theta_i = \sigma_i\theta$.

I have several questions here. Most fundamentally, what does he mean by $\prod_{i<j}(\theta_i - \theta_j)^2$? The discriminant is certainly a value in $L$, but this product leaves the variable $j$ open. My assumption was that this intended to mean $\prod_{j=1}^n\prod_{i < j}(\theta_i - \theta_j)^2$, but I'm not sure about this at all.

On the same note, I don't see what he means regarding multiplying the first $n-1$ columns by $\theta_i$ and then subtracting from the following. Does he mean that we transform the $i$th column $c_i$ by $c_i \mapsto (\theta_ic_i - c_{i+1})$? I tried to do the calculation using that, but I still had trouble with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On page 10, during the proof that $Tr_{L/K} \circ Tr_{M/L} = Tr_{M/K}$ for a tower of field extensions $K \subseteq L \subseteq M$, Neukirch partitions Hom$_K(L,\overline{K})$ by $\sigma \sim \tau$ if $\sigma|_L = \tau|_L$ into $m$ classes, each with representative $\sigma_i$.

Neukirch partitions $\operatorname{Hom}_K(\color{red}M, \overline{K})$ into $m$ classes using that relation.

> Now the part that's throwing me off is when he uses the fact that $$\sum_{\sigma \sim \sigma_i} \sigma x = Tr_{\sigma_i M/ \sigma_i L}(\sigma_i x).$$

To see this, you need to know that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\sigma_i L}(\sigma_i M, \overline{K}) = \{ \sigma \circ \sigma_i^{-1} \mid \sigma \sim \sigma_i \}$ (where $\sigma_i^{-1} : \sigma_i M \to M$ is an abuse of notation), which we now proof:

Take $\tau \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\sigma_i L}(\sigma_i M, \overline{K})$. We now define $\sigma: M \to \overline{K}$ to be $\tau \circ \sigma_i$. Then clearly it is a field homomorphism that fixes $K$, so $\sigma \in \operatorname{Hom}_K(M, \overline{K})$. Now, for any $y \in L$, we have $\sigma(y) = \tau(\sigma_i(y)) = \sigma_i(y)$ because $\tau$ fixes $\sigma_iL$. Therefore, $\sigma \sim \sigma_i$, so $\tau = \sigma \circ \sigma_i^{-1}$. This proves the forward inclusion.

The backward inclusion is left as an exercise.

Once you have this, you can calculate:
$$Tr_{\sigma_iM/\sigma_iL}(\sigma_i x) = \sum_{\tau \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\sigma_i L}(\sigma_i M, \overline{K})} \tau(\sigma_ix) = \sum_{\sigma \sim \sigma_i} (\sigma \circ \sigma_i^{-1})(\sigma_ix) = \sum_{\sigma \sim \sigma_i} \sigma x$$

> I have several questions here. Most fundamentally, what does he mean by $\prod_{i<j}(\theta_i - \theta_j)^2$? The discriminant is certainly a value in $L$, but this product leaves the variable $j$ open. My assumption was that this intended to mean $\prod_{j=1}^n\prod_{i < j}(\theta_i - \theta_j)^2$, but I'm not sure about this at all.

Indeed, $\prod_{i<j}(\theta_i - \theta_j)^2$ does mean $\prod_{j=1}^n\prod_{i < j}(\theta_i - \theta_j)^2$. Rather, my interpretation is that $\prod_{i<j}$ means $\prod_{\{(i,j) \mid i<j\}}$. You can rationalize this notation in any way you want.

> On the same note, I don't see what he means regarding multiplying the first $n-1$ columns by $\theta_{\color{red}1}$ **[correction mine]** and then subtracting from the following. Does he mean that we transform the $i$th column $c_i$ by $c_i \mapsto (\theta_ic_i - c_{i+1})$?

In English, when we subtract $3$ from $5$, we get $2$, and this is seen as performing an operation on $5$.

So, what he means (*Man sieht dies, indem man in der Vandermondeschen Matrix jede der $(n-1)$ ersten Spalten mit $\theta_1$ multipliziert und von der folgenden subtrahiert und so fortfährt.*), is to transform $c_{i+1} \mapsto c_{i+1} - \theta_1 c_i$. Let's take $n=3$ as an example. Our Vandermonde matrix is:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \theta_1 & \theta_1^2 \\ 1 & \theta_2 & \theta_2^2 \\ 1 & \theta_3 & \theta_3^2 \end{pmatrix}$$

If we perform the operation $c_{i+1} \mapsto c_{i+1} - \theta_1 c_i$, we get:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \theta_1 - \theta_1 \times 1 & \theta_1^2 - \theta_1 \times \theta_1 \\ 1 & \theta_2 - \theta_1 \times 1 & \theta_2^2 - \theta_1 \times \theta_2 \\ 1 & \theta_3 - \theta_1 \times 1 & \theta_3^2 - \theta_1 \times \theta_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

which we simplify to get:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & \theta_2 - \theta_1 & \theta_2(\theta_2 - \theta_1) \\ 1 & \theta_3 - \theta_1 & \theta_3(\theta_3 - \theta_1) \end{pmatrix}$$

We expand the determinant on the first row to get the same determinant as the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} \theta_2 - \theta_1 & \theta_2(\theta_2 - \theta_1) \\ \theta_3 - \theta_1 & \theta_3(\theta_3 - \theta_1) \end{pmatrix}$$

We can then factorize $(\theta_2 - \theta_1)$ from the first row and $(\theta_3 - \theta_1)$ from the second row to get:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \theta_2 \\ 1 & \theta_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

which is the Vandermonde matrix with $n$ being $1$ smaller, so we are done by induction.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the detailed answers! I see now what I got wrong regarding the Vandermonde matrix. And thanks even more for the Hom$_{\sigma_i L}$ thing. It's nice to know I wasn't just missing a totally obvious substitution or something!